# how can we close Solr Connection once it open in node js

Tags: node.js, solr, solrcloud

I am using solr-client in Node js with npm package and it working fine for me but
i want to know once we open connection how can we close it is their any option to close connection
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's even keeping the connection open? solr-client [uses the native `http` and `https` modules](https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client/blob/master/lib/solr.js#L13) in npm to make requests.

Comment: when solr down and  we send a request From UI that's issue How can I handle

Comment: So what you're looking for is a timeout option? If Solr really is down, the request should return immediately - but if it's non-responsive, the connection might wait until a timeout is reached. Do you want to lower the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

> When you are using solr-client in node js to work with solr, Node js solr-client does not maintain any connection, it only do http call to solr for select or update documents.